# Как в обработчике получить объект, соответствующий элементу XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vb.net

Проблема с получением объекта из элемента списка, который не в фокусе.
Для текущего элемента решается просто obj = ListView.SelectItem
Но если obj содержит, ну например checkbox, то его можно вкл/выкл вне фокуса, и тогда SelectItem не годится. Вот работающий пример на VB, но только для элементов в фокусе. А надо вне фокуса.

```
    Private Sub CheckBox_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If (CurrencyListView.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing) Then
        CurrentCurrency = CurrencyListView.SelectedItem
        If CurrentCurrency IsNot Nothing Then
            CurrentCurrency.IsActive = Not CurrentCurrency.IsActive
            Using db = New DbContextInfrastructureSqlite
                With db
                    .Currencies.Update(CurrentCurrency)
                    .SaveChanges()
                    CurrencyListView.ItemsSource = .Currencies.ToList()
                End With
            End Using
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Вы все таки поясните, чего вы хотите добиться. У вас SelectedItem - сложный и включает в себя checkbox, и вы хотите изменить у него свойство `Checked` из кода, так что-ли?

Comment: Не совсем. SelectItem - да, сложный и включает CheckBox, который может переключаться вне фокуса данного Item . Я хочу обработать его переключение в коде, но для этого мне надо получить не SelectedItem, а тот Item, который содержит кликнутый CheckBox. Как вариант - в коде переустанавливать фокус на этот кликнутый Item, но это как-то очень топорно.
Коротко говоря, в строке "CurrentCurrency = CurrencyListView.SelectedItem" вместо SelectedItem должен быть кликнутый Item.

Comment: Нашел аналогично, кмк, обсуждение с вашим участием, @Bulson
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971663/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-xaml?noredirect=1#comment1630852_971663]

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено.

```
    Private Sub CheckBox_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim mysender As CheckBox = sender                           ' получаем кликнутый CheckBox
    Dim mystackpanel As StackPanel = mysender.Parent            ' получаем StackPanel кликнутого CheckBox'a
    Dim myscrollviewer As ScrollViewer = mystackpanel.Parent    ' получаем ScrollViewer кликнутого CheckBox'a
    Dim mydata As Currency = myscrollviewer.DataContext         ' получаем DataContext из DataTemplate
    mydata.IsActive = mysender.IsChecked                        ' устанавливаем объект в контексте по значению контрола
    Using db = New DbContextInfrastructureSqlite                ' сохраняем контекст
        With db
            .Currencies.Update(mydata)
            .SaveChanges()
            CurrencyListView.ItemsSource = .Currencies.ToList()
        End With
    End Using
  End Sub
End Class
```

Код может быть сокращен, например путем установки собственно DataContext для вложенного StackPanel. Кроме того, можно было рассмотреть вариант восходящей маршрутизации события CheckBox'a.